# Can a set in MySQL be 0?

Tags: mysql

Can a [set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html) in MySQL be 0?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not?

```
CREATE TABLE t_set (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value SET('one', 'two'));

INSERT
INTO    t_set
VALUES  (1, 1);

SELECT  *
FROM    t_set;


id    value
----  ------
   1  one

UPDATE  t_set
SET     value = 0;

SELECT  *
FROM    t_set;

id    value
----  ------
   1
```

Answer (score 1):

> A SET is a string object that can
>   have zero or more values, each of
>   which must be chosen from a list of
>   allowed values specified when the
>   table is created. SET column values
>   that consist of multiple set members
>   are specified with members separated
>   by commas (“,”). A consequence of this
>   is that SET member values should not
>   themselves contain commas.
>
> For example, a column specified as
>   SET('one', 'two') NOT NULL can have
>   any of these values:
>
> '' 'one' 'two' 'one,two'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html